# UML Use Case Diagram: Branching scenarios

Tags: uml, use-case

Given the following scenario:

> If the credit card is declined, **the card will be ejected**. Otherwise, **some amount will be charged**.

How do I model this in a Use Case Diagram?

As far as I understand `extends`, (**A**) extending (**B**) means that: "If **A** happens, **B** *can* happen aswell". But this doesn't quite express the above scenario since one of these events/activities *has* to follow.

I think my main problem is that I have not quite internalised what you express and what you leave out in a Use Case Diagram.

Answer (score 2):

It's neither. The Use Case is `Pay X` or `Buy Y` or the like. This is shown in the UC bubble connected to the Actor getting that added value. Your description only shows an alternative in the flow of the UC, not another UC being included or extended. A UC is only about added value, not about functions.

As always I recommend reading Bittner/Spence.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like Payment using credit card is the use case here and two scenarios are possible
1.Payment successful
2.Payment declined

These are mutually exclusive paths of the use case and dont fit into the extends or includes relationships between use cases.

Includes relationship indicates a mandatory relationship while extends indicates a optional relationship